# Trying to input a file into an array using PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, file, directory

I currently have a magic 8 ball game which is coded like this:

```
import random
import string

choices = ['As I see it, yes.' , 'It is certain.' , 'Most likely.' , 'Outlook good' , 'Without a doubt' , 'yes - definitely' , 'You may rely on it' , 'Reply hazy, try again' , 'Ask again later' , 'Better not tell you now' , 'Cannot predict now' , 'Concentrate and ask again' , 'Dont count on it' , 'My reply is no' , 'My sources say no' , 'Outlook not so good' , 'Very doubtful' , 'Do I look like I care?' , 'Yeah, right' , 'Ask again later' , 'DUH!' , 'EOF']

print('I am the magic 8 ball. I will predict your future!')
raw_input('Ask me a question!')
answer = random.choice(choices)
print(answer)
```

This program runs just the way I want, however, what I WANT is to have the strings within the array, to be uploaded from a file, yet still have the output random. How would I do this? I am extremely new to PYTHON and am still learning all the functions. I've tried using FileInput and open() yet I have an error message that says "the 8 ball sayings.txt are not in the directory".

Can anyone explain what I need to do in order to put my strings on the correct path? Thank you!

Comment: It's probably easiest to just put it in the same folder as the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to create a plain-text (`.txt`) file that has one saying per line:

```
As I see it, yes.
It is certain.
Most likely.
Outlook good
...
```

Place this file in the same directory as your Python script.<sup>1</sup>

After that, you can open the file with [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), call its `read` method to read in the data, and then call [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to remove the trailing newlines:

```
import random

####################################
with open('file.txt') as f:
    choices = f.read().splitlines()
####################################

print('I am the magic 8 ball. I will predict your future!')
raw_input('Ask me a question!')
answer = random.choice(choices)
print(answer)
```

Note too that I used a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file, which will automatically close it for you when done.

---

<sup>1</sup>Otherwise, you will need to supply the full path to `open`:

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
```

Comment: gonna give this a try and come back if i have any issues, thank you!

Comment: so my main issue is saving my txt file to the proper directory. currently using Pyscripter as my compiler and it's just a confusing concept to me. I can pull up the directory menu and it lists 6 different things in my C drive. so my question is- where do I go to save my text file to the directory?

Comment: @Erowilder - I don't use Pyscripter, so I can't help you much with using the application.  Basically, the text file and the Python script need to be in the same place.  So, if the Python script is at `C:\Users\blah\script.py`, the text file needs to be placed at `C:\Users\blah\file.txt`.  Otherwise, if you save the text file to a different directory, you need to give the full path to `open`.

Comment: 1 more issue. So i have the path set and it runs, however now when i type my input, nothing appears. the txt file i saved has all my strings in it, so i don't quite understand why there is no output.

Comment: @Erowilder - I'm not sure either.  See my edit.  I included exactly how the code should look (I tested it too).